# Game Access Tokens in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement a short token system to allow players to share a 4 digit generated token so other players can locate and join their private game.

I am having trouble figuring out how to model this in firebase as I am new to flat data structures.

Here’s a simplified version of what I currently have implemented.

```
Users
    {4321}
        displayName
        ….
        openGames
            {1234}

games
    {1234}
        title
        …

openGames
    {1234}
    gameState       
            token
            public
            ...
            timeStamp
tokens
    {AcFk}: {1234}
```

**Assumptions**

I do not want logged in users to be able to iterate the tokens, openGames or games nodes.

**Using a Token**

When a player uses a token to find a game, I pull the token from the token table root.child(“tokens”).child({AcFk}) and use the value to find the open game.

**Security**

- Only allow a user to write a token for a game that they own. This is done by checking that a game with the key exists under their user profile when creating the key; enforced with a security rule; “.write”: “root.child('games').child(auth.uid).child(newData.val()).exists()”
- Only allow a user to write one token per game.

**Problem**

I don’t understand how to enforce the final one token per game rule. A malicious user could flood the table with fake tokens for a game they own and exhaust the token keyspace or increase likelihood of a collision requiring a new key generation.

```
tokens
    1111:{1234}
    1112:{1234}
    ..
    ZZZZ:{1234}
```

I guess I am trying to enforce a unique value rather than key. If I try and reverse the keys to acheive this I end up needing to iterate the tokens node (bad, now all tokens are public) to find the corresponding gameKey - mref.child(‘tokens’).orderbyvalue().equalto({token})

As there is no way to iterate in a security rule, I ended up trying a second index with the keys reversed to place some sort of lock and just got lost.

I think this is a weird one:one relationship that is complicated by the fact I don’t want people to iterate my data.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly you want a user to be able to join a game only once. If so you could reverse the key and value in your tokens object for example

tokens

```
1234:{1111}
1234:{1112}
..
1234:{ZZZZ}
```

Then when a user join for a second time(or multiple times) their first token will be overwritten so the above example becomes

tokens

```
1234:{ZZZZ}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The game the program models is actually taking place in the real world, often by people who have never met before and are in large groups. For various reasons sometimes they will have to exchange the token in person rather than discovering electronically.

The owner (originator) of the game generates the token and anyone who has it can enter the game. For this I need all logged in users to be able to read a token from the /tokens collection.

Comment: If I reverse the keys, I would need to do the token look up via child("tokens").orderbyvalue().equalto({token}). This requires the user to be able to iterate the /tokens node by placing a ".read": "auth != null" on the /tokens collection in the security rules.

A determined user could then just download a whole lost of the tokens. by grabbing child("tokens").

This is why I have used the token as the key for the collection, this allows me to do a child("tokens").child({token} while having ".read:" "false" on the /tokens collection to stop people iterating it.

Comment: This then leaves me with the issue of trying to enforce at the security level, the uniqueness of both the value (gameid) and the key (token). 

I.e  a gameid should never appear twice in the value of the collection and the token should never appear twice in the key of the collection (enforced by the fact its a key and I am happy for collisions to fail a write)

Something like ".uniqueIndexOn" ".value" on the /token collection is what I am trying to achieve.

I just realised I should have put this at the top.